# Exception in idempotent PUT request?

Tags: rest, exception, put, idempotent

I have an issue with implementing Idempotent operation in Put.

There is `Put` request which updates a field in a rest API resource.

But to implement Idempotency every repeated request should result in same state of the object.

We use a `database` what happens if an error occurs. Now does this mean `Idempotency` is lost? if not

Now going by the same defintion - If we have a conditional status change in a rest API on a field .eg) status field.

If the logic is to update the status field only if the parent property field  `locked==false`, we can throw an exception saying 'BusinessLogic exception cannot update status'

So in theory we have two operations we have similar situation:

1. one could be idempotent if not for real life errors which cannot be
   avoided
2. One should not be idempotent but we can make it similar

**question:**

How do you implement error handling based idempotency for put? and if error handling is OK does this mean even business logics could be made idempotency `Put`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to review the relevant definition of [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2)

> We use a database what happens if an error occurs. Now does this mean Idempotency is lost?

Idempotency is not lost.  Idempotent doesn't promise that every request will succeed; it only means that any [loss of property](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html) that occurs because the server received multiple copies of the request is the fault of the server.

> does this mean even business logics could be made idempotency Put?

Yes.  You can do this in one of two ways: by designing your domain application protocol so that the requests are inherently idempotent; or by using [conditional requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) to describe the "before" state that the request is intending to change.

Comment: @VoiceOfReason this is what I needed to know. thanks for the links. Can you please share some code samples or links on how to implement domain application protocol? It looks like a new term for me.

Comment: Review this talk by Jim Webber: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc